# cypress Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open

Tags: javascript, cypress

anyone has experience with that issue? and know how can I solve

looks like this is added **/Users/xlrs/test/project/cypress/screenshots**/Users/xlrs/test/project/cypress/snapshots/profile.cy.js/launches websitehola.snap.png'

`

```
Start generate report process
Read and merge jsons from "/Users/xlrs/test/project/cypress/reports/html/.jsons"
Enhance report
An error was thrown in your plugins file while executing the handler for the after:run event.

The error we received was:

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/xlrs/test/project/cypress/screenshots/Users/xlrs/test/project/cypress/snapshots/profile.cy.js/launches websitehola.snap.png'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:594:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:462:35)
    at convertImageToBase64 (/Users/xlrs/test/project/node_modules/cypress-mochawesome-reporter/lib/enhanceReport.js:111:52)
    at /Users/xlrs/test/project/node_modules/cypress-mochawesome-reporter/lib/enhanceReport.js:104:11
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createScreenshotsContextList (/Users/xlrs/test/project/node_modules/cypress-mochawesome-reporter/lib/enhanceReport.js:100:22)
    at attachScreenshotsToTestContext (/Users/xlrs/test/project/node_modules/cypress-mochawesome-reporter/lib/enhanceReport.js:76:9)
    at /Users/xlrs/test/project/node_modules/cypress-mochawesome-reporter/lib/enhanceReport.js:34:24
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/xlrs/test/project/node_modules/cypress-mochawesome-reporter/lib/enhanceReport.js:32:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at attachScreenshotsToSuiteTestsContext (/Users/xlrs/test/project/node_modules/cypress-mochawesome-reporter/lib/enhanceReport.js:31:12)
    at /Users/xlrs/test/project/node_modules/cypress-mochawesome-reporter/lib/enhanceReport.js:16:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at enhanceReport (/Users/xlrs/test/project/node_modules/cypress-mochawesome-reporter/lib/enhanceReport.js:6:18)
    at mergeAndCreate (/Users/xlrs/test/project/node_modules/cypress-mochawesome-reporter/lib/generateReport.js:19:3)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async generateReport (/Users/xlrs/test/project/node_modules/cypress-mochawesome-reporter/lib/generateReport.js:62:22)
    at async afterRunHook (/Users/xlrs/test/project/node_modules/cypress-mochawesome-reporter/lib/index.js:35:3)
    at async Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xlrs/test/project/node_modules/cypress-mochawesome-reporter/plugin.js:9:5)
    at async Object.handlerThatCallsUserDefinedHandler [as handler] (/Users/xlrs/test/project/node_modules/@applitools/eyes-cypress/src/plugin/pluginExport.js:49:11)`
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by changing this configuration in the `cypress.config.js` :

```
embeddedScreenshots: false,// from true to false
```

```
projectId: 'kp6yex',
  chromeWebSecurity: false,
  reporter: 'cypress-mochawesome-reporter',
  reporterOptions: {
    charts: true,
    reportPageTitle: 'custom-title',
    embeddedScreenshots: false,// from true to false
    inlineAssets: true,
    saveAllAttempts: false,
  },
```